Is this a standard conforming way for selective constructor "inheritance"?
In trying to inherit constructors selectively (ie just some of them) I found a way that seem to work with GCC:
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>

 struct B
 {
     B()
     {
         std::cout << std::string("B::B() called") << std::endl;
     }

     B(int)
     {
         std::cout << std::string("B::B(int) called") << std::endl;
     }

     B(long)
     {
         std::cout << std::string("B::B(long) called") << std::endl;
     }


     B(long, long)
     {
         std::cout << std::string("B::B(long, long) called") << std::endl;
     }
 };


 struct D : public B
 {
     D(int) = delete;
     D(long, long)
     {
         std::cout << std::string("D::D(long, long) called") << std::endl;
     }

     using B::B;
 };



 #pragma GCC diagnostic push // Ignore warnings from unused variables
 #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
 int main()
 {
     B b0;
     B b1(1);
     B b2(1, 2);
     D d0;
     // D d1(1);   error despite we might wish B::B(long) to be selected
     D d2(1, 2);
 }
 #pragma GCC diagnostic pop

ie those I don't want that using? brings down I just delete declare or define my own constructor in the derived class and both seem to stomp out the inherited overload.
Is this standard conforming? I also noted that it doesn't seem to matter whether the using declaration is first or last. Is that too standard conforming? It isn't entirely the same as selective inheritance as the deleted overload would still attract attention when resolving overloads (as the out commented line indicates).

You have a typo in "B::B(int) called"

error despite B::B(long) is a candidate This is not a candidate, the exact match D::D(int) is found.

@3CxEZiVlQ Checked and fixed (I hope)

@3CxEZiVlQ Yeah, that's a bit of the downside with the solution. One would have wished B::B(long) was selected

this is just how namelookup and overload resolution work. Yes this is specified in the standard

if you wish to call the long constructor you should pass a long rather than an int: https://godbolt.org/z/7be81coza

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, but that's not really the point. It's that when you only have a constructor accepting long you wouldn't want to have to explicitly cast the argument. Because of that this solution has it's shortcoming.

sorry I dont get your point. You do not have "only a consrtuctor accepting long". You have one (deleted) constructor for int and one for long. Hence when you pass an int the long constructor will not be called. You do not have to cast. You just have to pass a long

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Compare it with the solution where you just forward the call to base class constructor for those you want to inherit. They behave differently in this aspect, then D(1) would have worked.

sure. I still dont get your point. YOu deleted the int constructor so you cannot call it, why is this a surprise?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yeah, that's a bit of the downside with the solution. It's not possible even in theory. B::B(int) doesn't "know" anything about D, so it cannot construct it. Let's assume you could call it. Formally only B subobject would be created, data members and vtable of D would stay uninitialized. Only D::D(int):B(int) {} implementation makes sense. It works slightly diffeently if you have vrtual inheritance.

This is the expected behaviour, indeed since D(int) is explicitly deleted, it will be selected when calling with an int rather than an implicit conversion to another overload.
If you wanted D's int constructor to call B's long constructor you could just forward the call.
D(int x) : B((long)x) {}

This will behave as if you'd write
D d1(1l);

But it begs the question of why we're doing this, if the types should always be implicitly casted then why have all those implementations in the first place.

It's more of an example for demonstrating the technique and the question is about if this is standard conforming.
